# Wordpress WooCommerce display product attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display my product attributes with this code:

```
$versionvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_version');

      foreach ( $versionvalues as $versionvalue ) {
       echo $versionvalue->name;
        }
```

but nothing displays.

When I print_r `$versionvalues` I get this message:

```
WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Change `pa_version` to `pa_<your attribute name>`.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer my case for your reference.

Product attributes of my single product in database shown like this.

**Field :** _product_attributes

**Data:**

a:6:{s:11:"frame-style";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:11:"Frame
...
{s:4:"name";s:11:"Dimenssions";s:5:"value";s:24:"***52 | 17 | 138 | 32 | 132***";s:8:"position";s:1:"5";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:0;s:1...

Here I want to access **dimenssions** and show its values such as **52 | 17 | 138 | 32 | 132**

I can access it using **get_post_meta**. I want to show product Dimenssions from this **_product_attributes** attribute.

I can do it using this code:

```
$price_value = get_post_meta( $row['post_id'],  '_product_attributes', true );
$Dim  = $price_value['dimensions']['value'];
$DimArr = explode( '|', $Dim );
foreach ($DimArr as $D)
{
  echo $D . " - " ;
}
```

Output:

**56 - 15 - 133 - 46 - 137 -**

**Updated**
Use

```
global $product;
$attributes = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, '_product_attributes' ) );
```